# How do I find the smallest, largest value and total and the average in a 2D list that the user provides in python?

Tags: python, list, 2d

How do I find the smallest, largest value and total and the average in a 2D list that the user provides in python?

Comment: If my answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten it first.

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
flattened = [num for sublist in a for num in sublist]
min_val = min(flattened)
max_val = max(flattened)
sum_val = sum(flattened)
avg_val = sum(flattened) / len(flattened)
```

So in your case it'll be:

```
def list_stats(a):
    flattened = [num for sublist in a for num in sublist]
    min_val = min(flattened)
    max_val = max(flattened)
    sum_val = sum(flattened)
    avg_val = sum_val / len(flattened)
    return min_val, max_val, sum_val, avg_val

#Testing
a = [[1.2,3.5],[5.5,4.2]]
small, large, total, average = list_stats(a)
```

Comment: If your python is new enough, you can use `statistics.mean`

Answer (score 0):

> This what I have so far:

```
    a = [[]]
    total = 0
    counter = 0 
    small = a[0][0]
    for i in a: 
        if i > small:
            return True 
            total += i 
            counter += 1 
    average = total / counter
    return small, large, total, average 

#Testing
a = [[1.2,3.5],[5.5,4.2]]
small, large, total, average = list_stats(a)
```

> I'm getting the following two errors: small, large, total, average =
>   list_stats(a) small = a[0][0] IndexError: list index out of range

The function `list_stats` is not defined.

`a = [[]]` is a list that contains an empty list. `a[0][0]` is an element that does not exist.

Comment: the top part in my code (which I didn't include) is: def list_stats(a)

Comment: Also, even if you had included the function definition of your code, `a = [[]]` before the assignment statement `small = a[0][0]` will still result in `IndexError` exception as `a` is a list that contains an empty list and `a[0][0]` refers to an element that does not exist

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def list_stats(a):
    total = 0
    counter = 0 
    small = 99999
    large = -999
    for x in a:
        for y in x:
            if y < small: 
                small = y
            if y > large:
                large = y
            counter += 1
            total += y
    average = total / counter
    return small, large, total, average
```

I like Eric's answer better

Comment: Thanks! I think you can improve your solution by initializing small and large to None or the first number in `a` if it's not empty.

Comment: That's assuming that your list is in order and that you don't have negative numbers.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I think setting both `large` and `small` to the first value of the list and update them when a larger or smaller number is found will get you the right answer. The problem will be how to get the first number since a 2d list can be something like `[[], [1,2]]`. So I would say, for this approach, initialize both `large` and `small` to `None` and update them whenever the first value is found in the for-loop, then start doing the comparison when the next value is found. Of course, you'll also have to define the behavior when the list passed in has no number. e.g. `[[],[]]`, or `[]`